# jQuery programmatically Slideshow

Tags: jquery

I have a div, with a img tag inside. How can I programmatically slide show diferent images inside the div? I dont want to reinvent the wheel, but I prefer not to use a plugin.

Edit: I do have a list of images.

Comment: Do you have list of all the images you want to show as slide show? Or are you planing to make an ajax call per slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest one rotating images inside of div.

http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: Thx, Ill use a variation. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/ , it seems good.

Comment: Thx bro, but I dont want to use a plugin.

Comment: Some concepts it uses that might be useful. As image loading might not be a fast thing, it would be good idea to load images on background continously as soon as page loads. For that, load the first image and save it, on the onload event of that image load the second one and so on. then when your slides are 'sliding' your image will be ready for you, and you can manipulate it as you like.

Comment: For those ok with a plugin, Bootstrap Carousel is super straight-forward http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp